# Using knockout options.deferUpdates = true; causes issue for breeze navigation properties?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I would like to use the global knockout option

```
ko.options.deferUpdates = true;
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html

If I set this option, I get following error:

> knockout.debug.js:419 Uncaught Error: Collection navigation properties
>   may NOT be set.
>       at Function.koObj.equalityComparer (http://localhost:22657/bower_components/breeze-client/breeze.debug.js:17602:17)
>       at Function.isDifferent (http://localhost:22657/bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout.debug.js:1394:70)
>       at http://localhost:22657/bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout.debug.js:1358:22
>       at processTasks (http://localhost:22657/bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout.debug.js:1087:25)
>       at MutationObserver.scheduledProcess (http://localhost:22657/bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout.debug.js:1097:9)

If I remove the line `ko.options.deferUpdates = true;` ... the issue does not occur. I use knockout 3.4.1 and breeze-client 1.5.16.

The issue is hard to debug for me. Part of the breeze code:

```
      if (prop.isScalar) {
        if (propDescr) {
          Object.defineProperty(entity, propName, {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: koObj
          });
        } else {
          var koExt = koObj.extend({ intercept: { instance: entity, property: prop } });
          entity[propName] = koExt;
        }
      } else {
        val._koObj = koObj;
        // code to suppress extra breeze notification when
        // ko's array methods are called.
        koObj.subscribe(onBeforeChange, null, "beforeChange");
        // code to insure that any direct breeze changes notify ko
        val.arrayChanged.subscribe(onArrayChanged);

        koObj.equalityComparer = function () {
          throw new Error("Collection navigation properties may NOT be set.");
        };
        entity[propName] = koObj;
      }
```

Might the line `koObj.equalityComparer = ...` be a bug? 
Or do I need to make some changes to my code in order for the knockout deferUpdates option to play nicely with breeze?

Comment: What happens if you take out the `equalityComparer` in Breeze?

Comment: have you tried the workarounds mentioned in the documentation - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html#forcing-deferred-notifications-to-happen-early ?

Comment: a) If I comment out the line where the error is thrown the application seems to work....but I am not completely sure about that. The current test coverage is about 70 %. b) I saw the workarounds. However, I don't know where to apply them in respect to breeze ... and our application is quite large. Guess I need to create a smaller example that shows the same issue... hoped that someone already had to cope with the issue.

Comment: +1: I'm having the same issue. I was hoping to be able to use the option without many readjustments to the application. Unfortunately I don't have the time to digg into the inner workings of Breeze, so I was hoping one of the fellows of the Breeze-team could have a look at it and give some hints on how to integrate with this useful feature. ... But I don't think, the mentioned line is about the ```èqualityComparer``` is a bug. I suppose, the function is reassigned as soon as the navigation properties are loaded. In the meentime I'll have to keep the option disabled.

Comment: Perhaps file a report at https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js